# Magento Checkout API Payment Methods

Tags: magento2, checkout, api, payment, graphql

A lot of tutorials online show us what the flow is when ordering through the Magento2 Api.
Unfortunately, alot of these tutorials only display "Cash on delivery".

Magento DevDoc: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/rest/tutorials/orders/order-create-order.html
Other resource: http://magento2restapi.blogspot.com/

When posting the final request, The order gets created and all the required data is received in the backend. But how do we process payments trough the API system of magento.

I understand it's not easy to explain this in a reply to this post, but if you could point me towards the location where I can read more about this subject, that would be great.